# Java placeholder for comparing strings

Tags: java, string, wildcard

I want to test if the output looks like this:

```
String s1 = "You have 5 Dollar in your bank account."
```

To pass the test the Strings need to be equal, so I need a String that is equal:

```
String s2 = "You have (.*) Dollar in your bank account."
```

`s1.equals(s2)` shuold be true.

`(.*)` does not work, is there a simple way to implement this?

Comment: how about using regex?

Comment: A good first step is [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - `equals` mentions nothing about regex, `matches` does mention regex. Or Google "regex in Java".

Comment: Thank you, matches() was the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use `.*?` for a non greedy match, then

```
s1.matches(s2)
```

Will preform regex comparison

Also end `s2` with `account\\."` to get a literal period